# How to click on Google / YouTube links in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, url, youtube

So I am writing a c# program where the user can search for and watch youtube videos based on keywords. The user types their intended term into the search box, and then the program loads a list of videos with their intended search term. But I am wondering, is there a way to code it to click on the first - third video link when the search happens? I am also looking for it to close the current browser tab before opening the next.

Here is the code:

```
string[] words = {searchterms.text};
                            Console.WriteLine("Current word being searched for at " + DateTime.Now + ": " + words[r.Next(0, words.Length)]);
                            Console.WriteLine("Number of searches made since start: " + searchcount++.ToString());

                            string word = words[r.Next(0, words.Length)];

                            NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
                            nameValueCollection.Add("q", word);

                            webClient.QueryString.Add(nameValueCollection);

                            var youtubesearch = new ProcessStartInfo
                            {
                                FileName = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + word,
                                UseShellExecute = true
                            };
                            Process.Start(youtubesearch);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a Console app, you should know that the windows' shell do not support hyperlinks, which means you can't.
But i'm only deducing you're working on a Console app because of the Console.WriteLine() in your code, so could you be more specfifc ?

Comment: Sorry for late response. It is a WinForm app. The Console.WriteLine is so it writes some messages to the console instead of having a new windows popup every second.  The FileName URL is the youtube search URL + the generated word. I am wondering is there a way to open the first or third returned video?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can display the links in a label in order to be opened by the user in the browser, but if you want to display all the research results of youtube in your app, i think you have 2 solutions :

1. You can add an element called Web Browser, which is a web browser that will be displayed in your app (and you give it your URL
2. You also can work with the YouTube APIs. You can call an API using a link, and it will return you some non-displayable data, in JSON format usually, which you can use to display a list of the search result. You can maybe have the covers, tht title, description, etc of a video. I don't know how the YouTube APIs work, so here's [a link](https://developers.google.come/youtube/v3) so you can do some research of your own